# Custom page template for a node type?

Tags: 7, theming

I am creating a custom theme, and I need different page layouts depending on the node types. I can't use the node--xxxxx.tpl.php template, because I need control on the page layout outside the content of the particular page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a module for that: the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module is what you need.
You can do it with [page-[type] via preprocess functions](http://drupal.org/node/190815#comment-3084410).

Comment: thanks. I also found this discussion that contains I think a more concise form of the 2nd solution: http://drupal.org/node/982122